# Using an unknown generic interface in a static field returning a Func

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have the following static field in my class

```
private static Func<IDataReader, Project> Make = reader =>
    new Project
    {
        Name = reader["ProjectName"].AsId(),
        StartDate = reader["StartDate"].AsDateTime(),
        EndDate = reader["EndDate"].AsDateTime()
    };
```

I'm trying to do the same using a generic interface, but can't work out how to define the generic type. It would be something along the lines of this.

```
private static Func<IDataReader, IDefinition<T>> Make<T> = reader =>
    new Definition<T>
    {
        Name = reader["DefinitionName"].AsId()
    };
```

This obviousily doesn't work, but does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a generic field; you *can*, however, push this into a generic static type:

```
static class Foo<T> {
    internal static readonly Func<IDataReader, IDefinition<T>> Make = reader =>
        new Definition<T> {
            Name = reader["DefinitionName"].AsId()
        };
}
```

and use

```
Foo<YourType>.Make
```

You might want to tidy that up, though (the internal field, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could also transform the field to a generic method:

```
private static IDefinition<T> Make<T>(IDataReader reader)
{ 
    new Definition<T>
    {
        ...
    };
}

// call
var definition = Make<SomeType>(reader);
```

If you already have something of type T you can make a method that inferes T from usage:

```
private static IDefinition<T> Make<T>(IDataReader reader, T something)
{ 
    new Definition<T>
    {
        ...
    };
}

// call
var definition = Make(reader, someInstanceT);
```